# Python, Selenium and 2Captcha to solve Captcha not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, 2captcha

I'm trying to using 2Captcha to solve a recaptcha v2. When I run my code, it successfully gets the recaptcha result and stores it in result['code'], however when I execute the below code to submit, it seems the page only refreshes and the recaptcha does not get solved. Excuse my for my errors, I am extremely new to coding, and therefor my code is very crude and experimental. I am able to solve the captcha at https://2captcha.com/demo/recaptcha-v2?level=high using this code slightly modified, but haven't been able to get it working for my purpose. Can anyone explain to me what I could be doing differently?

```
driver.find_element_by_id("g-recaptcha-response").submit()
```

I have included my full code below as well

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json
import sys
import os
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha


loginInfo = json.load(open('logn.json'))
username = loginInfo['username']
password = loginInfo['password']


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.gaiaonline.com/")

loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]')
loginButton.click()

time.sleep(1)

usernameField = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
usernameField.send_keys(username)

passwordField = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
passwordField.send_keys(password)

rememberMe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="autologin"]')
rememberMe.click()

loginButton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signInButton"]')
loginButton2.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://www.gaiaonline.com/forum/compose/entry/new/79469475/")
time.sleep(4)

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
api_key = os.getenv('APIKEY_2CAPTCHA', 'My_API_KEY')

solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)

result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey=driver.find_element_by_class_name("g-recaptcha").get_attribute("data-sitekey"),
        url=driver.current_url)

print(result['code'])


driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="";')
driver.execute_script("""
  document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = arguments[0]
""", result['code'])
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("g-recaptcha-response").submit()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For the easy way's to handle Selenium and captcha is using "requests" library and handle the cookies between Selenium and your Requests.

Use cookies it will help solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).